# Laravel: Send an array through route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I was trying to send an array through a route to another view, but when i used the function `get_defined_vars()`, i realized that i was sending a string with the information. Is it possible to do that?

this form from my view should send the array to my route

```
            <form action="/trans" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="r" value="{{$cooperado}}">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                      <span>+</span>
                    </button>
                  </span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

then this route should send the array to the other view

```
Route::post('/trans',  function(){
    $j = Input::get('r');
    return view('movs.create')->with(['j'=>$j]);
});
```

this is the controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Movimentacoes;
class MovimentacoesController extends Controller
{
public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('movs.create');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is not passing in the controller at all??

Comment: no, it should right? i'm still learning about MVC

Comment: if you call return dd($j) what it looks like? may be your $cooperado is formatted as string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

routes.php

```
Route::post('/trans',  'MovimentacoesController@create');
```

controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Movimentacoes;

class MovimentacoesController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $j = $request->request->get('r');
        return view('movs.create')->with(['j' => $j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: still getting string, dont know why

Comment: <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="r[]" value="{{$cooperado}}">   attribute r - add square brackets?

Comment: now it recognize as an array, but with just one value, the string

Comment: you may use "implode" function for convert $cooperado to string, send it via form, and use "explode" function for convert string to array where necessary

Answer (score 1):

Code like this In the form tag:

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="r[]" value="{{$cooperado}}">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="r[]" value="{{$cooperado}}">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="r[]" value="{{$cooperado}}">
```

submit this form
then the `Input::get('r')` will be Array!
I hope it helps you.